# Problem in loading ggplot2 in R version 4.0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have installed `ggplot2` in R but when I try to load it, R gives this ERROR message:

```
library(ggplot2)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.6 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.7 is required

What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start a new Session, update all Packages, most importantly `rlang` and try loading `ggplot2` again.

Comment: If that doesn't work, what I usually do is run `.libPaths()` which shows where your R packages are being installed to. I navigate to that location, manually delete all the folders there. Then reinstall packages using the usual `install.packages()` etc. That fixes that error message ~90% of the time for me. (note: I don't actually know what the underlying problem is - keen to hear it if someone knows!)

Comment: OP, it says right in the error your solution.  You have `rlang` version 0.4.6, but you need to use version 0.4.7.  Update `rlang` (`install.packages("rlang")`), and then you should re-install `ggplot2` (`install.packages("ggplot2")`).  That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install the full **tidyverse** package, it will load all graphics dependencies include gglot2 and its dependencies too.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

As mentioned here:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/i-cant-load-ggplot2-in-my-library-in-r-version-3-4-3/6466

Answer (score 0):

I am working on **WINDOWS OS** and I had same problems with loading **`ggplot2`** and other libraries. I tried to install it like it was suggested in other threads, but it didn't solve the problem. I found some similar issues in other topics, and i figured out that my Rstudio console wanted to have fresh a toolchain bundle called **`Rtools`**. It can be downloaded from [CRAN REP](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).

You have to pick appripiote version for your Rengine version. If you do not know what version of R you have, you have to simple type `R.version` in console, and then download proper version of `Rtools`. After that, i updated every libraries in Rstudio. `ggplot2`, `tidyverse` and many other are working properly from that time

I hope that it could help somebody :)